# TranslationByMarkupExtension: On startup populate MainApplication.xaml with custom values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, internationalization

i have followed the article: [Localization of a WPF application using a custom MarkupExtension](http://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html) for internazionalizing my app.

In my MainWindow.xaml i have:

```
<Button x:Name="ServiceButton" Content="{l:Translate service.button.start}" Click="toggle_service_click" />
```

As you can see the translate markup **{l:Translate service.button.start}** is written to retrieve the string *service.button.start* in my current locale resource file when app is loaded, but if the service is already started the markup string should be *service.button.stop*

So, in practice, whene i run my app, if the service is started:

```
<Button x:Name="ServiceButton" Content="{l:Translate service.button.stop}" Click="toggle_service_click" />
```

otherwise

```
<Button x:Name="ServiceButton" Content="{l:Translate service.button.start}" Click="toggle_service_click" />
```

How i can set the corret markup "On the fly" directly in the xaml file before that translationManager parse it?

**EDIT:**
I have tryed to bind it in my DataContext like this:
*dataContext*

```
public object ServiceTplString
{
    get
    {
        var isr = ServiceHandler.Instance.serviceIsRunning("service_alias", "service_name");
        return "{l:Translate service.button." + ( (isr) ? "stop" : "start" ) + "}";
    }
}
```

*MainApplication.xaml:*

```
<Button x:Name="ServiceButton" Content="{Binding ServiceTplString}" Click="toggle_service_click" />
```

but doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-thinking it.  Bind to an object, `ServiceTplString`, like you've done, and then just change the value of `ServiceTplString`:

```
ServiceTplString = Resources.StartLabel
```

or

```
ServiceTplString = Resources.StopLabel
```

depending on what you need.

I'm assuming you have your internationalized text in resource files; you may have it elsewhere.

Here's the property you'll want to use:

```
private string serviceTplString;

public string ServiceTplString
{
    get
    {
        return serviceTplString;
    }
    set
    {
        serviceTplString = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ServiceTplString");
    }
}
```

That way when you update its value, the value will be propagated to the bound control.